# Edge-to-endgrain butt joint

Tags: wood, framing, joints

I need to make this out of 2x4 lumber.

[image]

It's not load-bearing but needs to be somewhat stiff against skew (L-to-R in the image above). The part I'm not sure about is the end-grain to edge butt joints like this:

[image]

Given the difficulty I've had in locating examples on the web I assume this joint isn't common.  Most everything I found was end-to-face (sill to stud) and furniture woodworking joints (mortise & tenon, dowel, pocket screws) which are kind of overkill for a simple frame.

What is the accepted way of accomplishing this, and is there a bracket or connector I can use to increase strength?  A connector would need to have an "H" shape and I've not found anything like that online.  Or, is it as simple as using 6" screws to go through the width of the base board?

Comment: is this a carpetery question that might be better answered in woodworking, or is this a framing question? 6" screws are probably too short, end grain is weak, maybe 10" or longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would a truss connector plate be what you are looking for? This joint is quite common in a truss.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the simplest and cheapest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to add stiffness to prevent skewing is to add diagonal bracing, or completely sheath one side with plywood or OSB.  Then the butt joints can just be held together with toenailed nails.  Without knowing what this is for, I realize it may not be workable.

Answer (score 1):

You could tonail some screws at an angle through the joint. You could use a bunch of corner braces. You could also use nail plates across both sides of all the joints. 6" screws all the way through s not a bad way to go also. Each approach has tradeoffs between strength, ease of installation, and appearance. You could use a combination of methods too.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the mortice and tenon joints - one way to get the structural rigidity and avoid unsightly brackets sitting above the surface.

The [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortise_and_tenon) shows some versions possible.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier to answer if you told us what this is for.

The left-to-right skew is known as "racking".

To prevent racking, the best practice for this is not using (solely) 90-degree joints.  Replace the middle stud with two diagonal studs.

For fasteners, either toe-nail into the horizontal 2x4s, or pocket screws, or truss plates.

[image: 2x4 truss example]

Also-- this is not endgrain to endgrain.  This is endgrain to crossgrain.